# IOS - fix portrait viewcontroller inside multiple tabbar and navigation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

**I have a diagram very complicated, and I want to fix portrait UIViewController inside multiple TabBarController and NavigationController, I'm using this code in UIViewController do fix TabBar and Navigation:**

```
@implementation UINavigationController (LoginIphone)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
@implementation UITabBarController (ChannelViewController)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // You do not need this method if you are not supporting earlier iOS Versions
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**and this code inside do fix UIViewController** but it doesn't work.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

[image]

**Anyone have solution for this problem, thank to read this article!**

Comment: By "multy" do you mean "multiple"?

Comment: let you see the image :)

Comment: Did you debug with breakpoints to see wether auto rotating methods are called properly for your collection controllers?

Comment: Why did you override `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` for UINavigation controller only?

Comment: In general you should subclass and not override methods using categories

Comment: @Andrea: Can you say more details it? I don't understand

Comment: @BlueSky most probably it won't solve the problem, but you should subclass UINavigationController and UITabbarController to override the orientation methods, instead of overrinding them in categories as you did. Is just good programming behaviour.

Comment: @Andrea: OK, I'll do, now I write on UIViewController, but UIViewController doesn't fix Portrait

Comment: @Andrea Apple docs says "This class is not intended for subclassing" about both UITabBarController and UINavigationController. Categories work just fine.

Comment: @Stas there was that advice, in the updated DOC there isn't anymore

Comment: I'm try many solution but it's not work, somebody help me !

Answer (score 0):

Your `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method should be:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: I do this, it's not work, because UIViewController inside multiple Tabbar and Navigation :(

Answer (score 0):

project Targets --> click on "Summary" tab and choose your Orientation in "Supported interfaces Orientations"

Comment: As I understand, app must support all orientations for all VCs except one. So it won't help.